# Accessing props in onSubmit method of react-dropzone-uploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state, react-dropzone

I am using [`react-dropzone-uploader`](https://github.com/fortana-co/react-dropzone-uploader) to upload files. Everything works OK; except that I want the parent Component to be updated after clicking on submit button. What should I do?

This is the part of code I use:

```
export default () => {

  const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
    console.log('uploads files:', files, this)
    // There is no access to props here.
  }

  return (
    <Dropzone
      getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
      onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      accept="image/*,.pdf,.doc,.docx"
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Your component would be getting the props from parent as part of function call `export default (props) => { } `. You can use the same props object in your handleSubmit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a functional component you don't need `this` and you get props from

```js
export default (props) => {

  const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
    console.log('uploads files:', files)
    // Get set state function from props
    props.setFiles(files)
  }

  return (
    <Dropzone
      getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
      onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      accept="image/*,.pdf,.doc,.docx"
    />
  )
}
```

And in the parent, you can call this component as

```js
...
const [files, setFiles] = useState(null)
...
return (
  <div>
  <div>Drop files</div>
  <CustomDropzone setFiles={setFiles} />
  </div>
)
```